# How do I detect a memory leak that is not showing up while profiling in Netbeans?

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, memory-leaks, profiling

The total memory used by the program is not **nearly** recorded by Netbeans' built-in profiler. There are some very large objects that are not showing up, such as a WriteableRaster (which I'll be doing away with soon). In terms of magnitude: if the profiler doesn't account for garbage collection, I'll get a total of ~2.5GB from the profiler while the program is using ~6GB. If the profiler *does* account for garbage collection, then it will display ~100MB being used (live memory), while the program is still using ~6GB. Is there any way to track larger objects with the profiler or will I have to use a different tool?

Comment: How do you know that *the program is using ~6 GB*?

Comment: Is this 6GB of _address space_ or 6 GB of _actual memory_? This is quite different.

Comment: Tried http://visualvm.java.net ?

Comment: @assylias, this is the amount of memory reported by the task manager. I'm not certain on the specifics, but I am certain the program is filling all my memory [8GB], after being at a "resting state" around 2GB. The program is supposed to use a large amount of memory, but after some small change I don't remember it's been leaking and I'm trying to find the source.

Answer (score 1):

The amount shown by the task manager is the total size of your heap, which might be mostly free / unused. So it probably has nothing to do with a leak.

If you want to use less memory you can decrease the maximum heap size parameter but you might run out of memory at some stage...

Comment: Yes, after using VisualVM I found that the heap was often nearly double what's being used. However, the amount of memory actually used by the application is continually growing.